# Android Studio with AndroidAnnotations -> these types will not undergo annotation processing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-annotations

I am not sure if it is Android Studio ( 0.1.9 ) or AndroidAnnotation problem, however, lately I cannot make and compile my AndroidAnnotations projects.

Ok, so I try to make project and this is what I got in "Messages" window:

```
Information:Round 1:
Information:    input files: {com.antyzero.sidereelo.ui.activity.SplashActivity}
Information:    annotations: [com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity, java.lang.Override]
Information:    last round: false
Information:Processor com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor matches [com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity] and returns true.
Information:Note: Starting AndroidAnnotations annotation processing
Information:Round 2:
Information:    input files: {com.antyzero.sidereelo.ui.activity.SplashActivity_}
Information:    annotations: [java.lang.Override]
Information:Processor com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor matches [] and returns true.
Information:Round 3:
Information:    input files: {}
Information:    annotations: []
Information:    last round: true
Information:Compilation completed successfully with 1 warning in 17 sec
Information:0 errors
Information:1 warning
Warning:: Unclosed files for the types '[dummy1372862415557]'; these types will not undergo annotation processing
```

Nothing less, nothing more. In result I don't have my SplashActivity_ created. This message is from brand new project but my old projects are also affected.

Answer from [Android Studio: Use AndroidAnnotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577012/android-studio-use-androidannotations) is not helpful.

I was working with AA and IntelliJ weeks before Android Studio without problem. IMO it might happen after latest Android Studio update, but maybe there is some kind of solution for this right now, if not I will report this to Android Studio team. Thanks for help.

One more thing. My projects are using Maven and building them from CLI works fine, all classes are generated as they should be.

Comment: No, I dropped AA, too many issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same problem when trying to inject a view with `@ViewById`, and the problem was that **I was declaring the field private**. Declaring it **at least protected** fixed the issue!

Before:

```
@ViewById
private NoListResultsView noResultsView;
```

After

```
@ViewById
protected NoListResultsView noResultsView;
```